# Firebase Phone Authentication get error in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I am testing Firebase Phone Verification in Xamarin. Here are the steps I took:

1. Add NuGet Package: Xamarin.Firebase.Auth, Xamarin.Firebase.Core in Project Android.
2. To start PhoneNumber Verification:

- Add Class: **AccountServiceAuthPhone.cs**

  ```
  [assembly: Dependency(typeof(AccountServiceAuthPhone))]
  namespace XXXXX.Droid
  {
    public class AccountServiceAuthPhone : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks, IAccountService
    {
        public AccountServiceAuthPhone()
        {
        }

        //const int OTP_TIMEOUT = 30; // seconds
        private string _verificationId;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
        private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

        public override void OnVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PhoneAuthCredential created Automatically");
        }

        public override void OnVerificationFailed(FirebaseException exception)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Verification Failed: " + exception.Message);
        }

        public override void OnCodeSent(string verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken)
        {
            base.OnCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
            _verificationId = verificationId;
        }
        public Task<bool> SendOtpCodeAsync(string phoneNumber)
        {
            PhoneAuthOptions options =
            PhoneAuthOptions.NewBuilder(mAuth)
                    .SetPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
                    .SetTimeout((Java.Lang.Long)60L, TimeUnit.Seconds) // Timeout and unit
                    .SetActivity(Platform.CurrentActivity)              // Activity (for callback binding)
                    .SetCallbacks(mCallbacks)   // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                    .Build();
            PhoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber(options);
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        private void OnAuthCompleted(Task task, TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs)
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled || task.IsFaulted)
            {
                // something went wrong
                tcs.SetResult(false);
                return;
            }
            _verificationId = null;
            tcs.SetResult(true);
        }

        public Task<bool> VerifyOtpCodeAsync(string code)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_verificationId))
            {
                var credential = PhoneAuthProvider.GetCredential(_verificationId, code);
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                FirebaseAuth.Instance.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential)
                    .ContinueWith((task) => OnAuthCompleted(task, tcs));
                return tcs.Task;
            }
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
    }
  }
  ```
- Add interface **IAccountService.cs**

  ```
  public interface IAccountService
  {        
      Task<bool> SendOtpCodeAsync(string phoneNumber);
      Task<bool> VerifyOtpCodeAsync(string code);
  }
  ```
- Login.xaml.cs

  ```
  private async void _nextlogin_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (txt_phone.Text != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_phone.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "").Replace("&", "")))
      {
        string phone = txt_phone.Text;

        await _accountService.SendOtpCodeAsync(phone);

        Preferences.Set("PhoneGetOTP", txt_phone.Text);
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ConfirmOTP());
      }         
  }
  ```

3. Go to google cloud console, select your project.
4. Click on the navigation menu and select APis & services and then select Dashboard.
5. Click on enable api and services and enable API " Android Device Verification".
6. Add SHA-1 and Download and replace the latest google-services.json file in your project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

However when I do Debug, it gives an error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object". Looks like it doesn't execute into: `public Task<bool> SendOtpCodeAsync(string phoneNumber)`. Looking forward to everyone's help. Thank you

Comment: you need to use the debugger and either look at the stack trace to find the root line that causes the error, or interactively step through the code to find it.  Once you find it, examine each element of the line to determine which one is null.

Comment: I have solved this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you, use this method for SendOtpCodeAsync:

```
 private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _phoneAuthTcs;

    public Task<bool> SendOtpCodeAsync(string phoneNumber)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(phoneNumber))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }

        try
        {
            _phoneAuthTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();


            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.Instance;

            PhoneAuthOptions options = PhoneAuthOptions.NewBuilder(auth)
            .SetPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)       // Phone number to verify
            .SetTimeout((Java.Lang.Long)120L, TimeUnit.Seconds) // Timeout and unit
            .SetActivity(Platform.CurrentActivity)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
            .SetCallbacks(this)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            .Build();

            PhoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber(options);

            return Task.FromResult(true);// _phoneAuthTcs.Task; //Task.FromResult(true);//
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Firebase Phoneauth Exception:" + Ex.Message + "//////");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This works for me.
Code taken from: [Xamarin.Andorid Firebase Phone Auth, SMS OTP Send , User Add](https://mistic.co.kr/74)